# ImportError: no module named miniconda

Tags: python, importerror, miniconda

I've installed miniconda on my mac following the instructions from the python website. However, when I write any new script and try and import miniconda, matplotlib or Pandas, I get the error above.

My script so far

```
from miniconda import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
```

CORRECTED

my code is now

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
```

I'm now getting the same import error for pandas and seaborn.

**UPDATED:**

Turns out the corrected code above works and the issue was with Python runner. The code runs when executed through the terminal. Probably an issue with permissions!

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ale/Desktop/display_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from miniconda import *
ImportError: No module named miniconda

Comment: you can not import miniconda. Miniconda in an installer with condo package manager and python in it. So this line Is **from miniconda import ** is causing the error. Remove that and shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: I'm getting the same import error now for Pandas and Seaborn instead

Comment: you need to install numpy, pandas and seaboard using condo package manager. In the first place did you install those packages?. Do **condo install pandas** and see if you still get the error

Comment: I used pip to install them both

Comment: unless you are absolutely sure about what you are doing, I suggest you use **condo install <package-name>** to avoid having issues when using condo.

Comment: They're definitely already installed because I get requirement satisfied when I try to install them again

Answer (score 1):

Miniconda is not a module indeed it is a variant of Anaconda python distribution, hence you could not import it. You could get further info about miniconda from the link below.

https://conda.io/miniconda.html

Comment: See comments above